# how can I combine 2 array to create array of arrays in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have latsArr and LongsArr filled from firebase automatically.
I want to populate latsAndLongsArray in viewDidLoad function. How can I do that?

```
var latsArr = [1111.0,2222.0,333.0]
var longsArr = [444.0,555.0,666.0]

var latsAndLongs = [[111.0,444.0],[222.0,555.0],[333.0,666.0]]
```

Comment: How can this _not_ be a duplicate? And 4 almost identical answers!

Comment: Another question is why you are receiving two arrays from the server when the values should be paired between them. This sounds more like a poor design on the server side that needs to be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var latsAndLongs = zip(latsArr, longsArr).map({[$0.0, $0.1]})
```

Comment: how does your answer is different from PGDev's answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `zip(_:_:)` and `map(_:)` methods combined to get the expected result:

```
let latsAndLongs = zip(latsArr, longsArr).map { [$0.0, $0.1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option (which uses tuples instead of arrays) is to use [`zip`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip).

```swift
var latsArr = [1111.0,2222.0,333.0]
var longsArr = [444.0,555.0,666.0]

var latsAndLongs = zip(latsArr, longsArr)
// latsAndLongs == [(1111.0, 444.0), (2222.0, 555.0), (333.0, 666.0)]
```

Comment: this will produce array of tuples instead of array of array